# How to insert form input field in table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have displayed all the student's name in table format through ajax. Now I want to associate a form input field to each student so that I can insert his marks and store it in database? How can I achieve this?
Below is my code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select_std() {
        var ali = $('#class_std').val();
        $('#std_name').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'admin/test/'?>" + ali,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(res) {
                $('#myTable tbody').append(res);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and my controller :

```
public function test($id=''){
  $table='students';
  $columns=array('*');
  $where=array('c_id'=>$id);
  $data['rcd']= $this->Crud->get_records($table, $columns, $where)->result();

  foreach ($data['rcd'] as $value) {
    $output = "<tr><td>".$value->Name."</td><td>90</td><td>very good<td></tr>";
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

This is my table format in which I have showed all the student's names in the first `<td>` through ajax from database. and I want to make the second `<td>` as input field to store his marks in database.

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="myTable" class="table table-boardered table-responsive" id="example2">
    <thead>
        <th width="20px;">Name</th>
        <th>Marks obtained(100)</th>
        <th>comments</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="std_name">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You mean `$output = "<tr><td><input type='text' value='".$value->Name."' /></td><td>90</td>`

Comment: What have you tried yet? We're here to help, not to code for you...

Comment: Mr. Twinfriends! i have write<td><?php form_input(array('type'="number",class=>"form-control")); ?></td> as i want to make my second <td> as input field. but it's display me all the text as i typed here

Comment: Mr. Twinfriends! i have write<td><?php form_input(array('type'="number",class=>"form-control")); ?></td> as i want to make my second <td> as input field. but it's display me all the text as i typed here

Comment: $value->name(this is from database)

Comment: _“but it's display me all the text as i typed here”_ - of course it does, when you just insert this into the existing line, `$output = "<tr><td>".$value->Name."...` - you are already “in PHP mode” here with that syntax, so using `<?php` again is of course nonsense. If that function `form_input` returns a string, then you could directly concatenate that into the string you are creating here.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a form on the table/your loop so that every student has a designated input field then if you want to make an action to a specific student get the ID of the specific student then inserts it to the DB. (get(id) = idfromdb).

```
<?php foreach ($data['rcd'] as $value) { ?>
<tr><td><?php $value->Name ?></td><td>90</td><td>very good<td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <input field here>
 <input button value=$value[id]> 
 </td></tr> <?php } ?>
```

then in the next page or the same page its up to you:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['button name'])){ 
   $id = $_POST[button name];
insert your data to your db where $id = idfromdb }?>
```

ahaha sorry dude I forgot php. :(

Comment: yeah! great the samething which i want.. but kindly, give me the code i am very stuck here

Comment: I can give you some code that can give you hints because I forgot the whole syntax in PHP. I'm sorry mate just research it. :) ok just wait a little bit.

Comment: very nice you my dear Deee